# unexpected type 'USN' when class member marked as [DataMember]

Tags: c++, wcf, visual-studio-2008, wcf-binding

In my C++ project, I have a SOAP class:

```
namespace soapcon
{
    [DataContract]
    public ref class z
    {
    public:
        [DataMember]
        int USN;
    };
}
```

If the `USN` member is marked as `[DataMember]`, I get a compiler error `syntax error : unexpected type 'USN'`. However, if I comment out the `[DataMember]`, everything compiles with no errors.

Is `USN` a type used by WCF, or is there some other cause of this error?

Comment: `USN` is not a type I've seen in WCF.  My C++ is *extremely* rusty (as in I haven't written any in 20+ years), but is it possible you have a type `USN` defined somewhere else (or maybe in a 3rd party library)?

Comment: I've searched my code, and found no trace of USN. Also, if it is a type, why would commenting out the `[DataMember]` allow it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `USN` is defined in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h` as  `typedef LONGLONG USN`.

I found this out by putting a

```
typedef int USN;
```

line *outside* the namespace, which caused the compiler to report an error that reported the location of the original typedef.

What appears to be happening is that declaring `USN` to be a `[DataMember]` causes the compiler to look in the global namespace, and find the typedef for `USN`.